# How to apply css to the maintenance page?

Tags: 7, theming, maintenance-mode

I need to work on some serious update to my D7 website. So I put my site in maintenance mode. I'm able to personalize the maintenance page by creating *maintenance-page.tpl.php* in my theme's template directory and it works like charm, no issues. The problem is, none of my theme *css* files are loaded when I'm opening the site in maintenance mode.

I'd really like to prettify the maintenance page for any visitors who visits the site in the mean time (while I'm updating). How do I do that? BTW, I'm using omega theme stable release.

Comment: Are you seeing the system stylesheets being loaded in the head?

Comment: yes I can see some system stylesheets are loaded like `@import url("http://sitename/modules/system/system.theme.css?mm4f6a")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override the maintainence stylesheet in the theme layers .info file...

```
  stylesheets[all][] = system.maintenance.css
```

To be honest if none of your theme stylesheets are loading then not sure it will work but ideally it should.

Heres some more info on theming the maintence page...

http://drupal.org/node/195435

---

**UPDATE**

Alternatively, try the following in your theme...

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_maintenance_page().
 */
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$variables) {
  drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('theme', 'YOUR_THEME') . '/css/maintenance-page.css');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But still no luck. 
omega theme uses different format to include css, like this:
`; OPTIONAL STYLESHEETS

css[global.css][name] = Your custom global styles`

I tried that too, but still same.

Comment: Updated answer, try that?

Comment: Great.. the alternate option works like expected.. thanks. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can even add direct css by following stylesheet link

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/css/maintaince.css">
```

Just remember to add full address to your theme i.e. `sites/all/themes/YOUR_THEME/YOUR_CSS`